# Nested Scala singletons from Java code

Tags: java, scala

I have the following Scala (2.8) code:

```
object A {
  val message = "hello"
  object B {
    val message = "world"
  }
}
```

And a similar Java class:

```
public class C {
  public static String message() {
    return "HELLO";
  }
  public static class D {
    public static String message() {
      return "WORLD";
    }
  }
}
```

These work as I'd expect when I call them from Scala:

```
scala> A.message  
res0: java.lang.String = hello

scala> A.B.message
res1: java.lang.String = world

scala> C.message  
res2: java.lang.String = HELLO

scala> C.D.message
res3: java.lang.String = WORLD
```

But when I try something similar from Java, the compiler doesn't like the second line:

```
System.out.println(A.message());
System.out.println(A.B.message()); // cannot find ... symbol  : variable B ...
System.out.println(C.message());
System.out.println(C.D.message());
```

It's clear why this is the case when I look at the class files with `javap`. I know I can use

```
System.out.println(A$B$.MODULE$.message());
```

instead, or add something like `val getB = B` to my `A` object and replace the second line with

```
System.out.println(A.getB().message());
```

Is there a standard way to use nested Scala singleton objects from Java code?

Comment: Well, `A$B$.MODULE$` _is_ a standard way, even if it is not a particularly nice standard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm have little knownledge of Scala, but considering [the way Scala is compiled into bytecode](http://blog.thegodcode.net/post/239967776/a-look-at-how-scala-compiles-to-java), I think you have exposed the only two options you have.